# Get Contact Group by its name (instead of checking each item in olFolderContacts)

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to address a Contact Group of my Outlook. Right now I have to go through all the items in my Contacts:

```
Set ContactsFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
Set contactItems = ContactsFolder.Items
iCount = contactItems.Count
For i = 1 To iCount
    Set thisItem = contactItems.Item(i)
    If TypeName(thisItem) = "DistListItem" And thisItem = "promo_spam" Then
     Set myDLGroup = thisItem
     Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

is there any better way to get it? I was thinking about something like ContactsFolder.Items.Find but couldn't find the right way to use it...

Comment: Set myDLGroup = contactItems("promo_spam")

Comment: ouch, that easy! Thanks! Please add it as an answer, I'll mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are using is normally for listing items in a group.

If you already know the name then:

```
Set myDLGroup = contactItems("promo_spam")
```